# Expires headers for url rewrite rules in nginx

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx, http-headers

In my nginx config I have some url rewrite rules for images as seen below:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/custom/path/(.*)/(.*)-(.*).jpg$ /media/images/products/$1/$3.jpg last;
}
```

They work just fine. I'm also trying to set `Expire` headers for all static resources (images, css, js). I've added the following block for that:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires 1y;
}
```

This works fine for everything except the images that have the url rewrite rules (which return `404 Not found`). Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the rewrite rule inside the same block as the expires rule did the trick:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires 1y;

    rewrite ^/custom/path/(.*)/(.*)-(.*).jpg$ /media/images/products/$1/$3.jpg last;
}
```